# get direction functionality on map app iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

I want to implement get direction functionality between two locations in iOS default Map App and I've tried this

```
Class itemClass = [MKMapItem class];
if (itemClass && [itemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {
    // Use iOS 6 maps
    NSString *latString = @"23.0300";
    NSString *longString = @"72.5800";

    CLLocationCoordinate2D  ctrpoint;
    ctrpoint.latitude = [latString doubleValue];
    ctrpoint.longitude = [longString doubleValue];

    MKPlacemark *placemark2 = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:ctrpoint addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark2];
    [mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
}
```

But it shows the directional error as below:

[image: Get Direction Error]

I even opened the map app, located my current location, added one pin on the map nearest to my location, and get direction is still not working on that.

Also "In short Get Direction is not working completely even in native app" Can any one help me to achieve this?

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: at Rajkot, Gujarat, India. My current Lat Long is :22.3000, 70.7833

Comment: Can you get directions in the regular maps app?

Comment: No man i didn't!!! :(

Answer (score 7):

Apple Maps do not support directions in India.

You could use Google Maps for directions, if its available on the phone. 
If Google Maps App is not available resort to Apple maps.

Following code block might be of some help.

```
    NSURL *appUrl;

    //Is Google Maps App Installed ?
   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {

        // Use Google Maps App to get Directions
       appUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?daddr=%f,%f&saddr=%f,%f",
                            destLocation.coordinate.latitude, destLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                            _currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,_currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]];
    }

    // Google Maps not Installed
    else {

        // Use Apple Maps App to get Directions
        appUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=%f,%f&saddr=%f,%f",
                           destLocation.coordinate.latitude, destLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                           _currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,_currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]];
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appUrl];
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Apple feature availability](http://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#maps-directions), directions are not supported in India.

Same thing seems to go for iOS 6, according to [this post](http://features.en.softonic.com/ios-6-features-dont-work-everywhere).

Comment: thanks i guess you're right coz when i changed the lat long of my simulator and destination location it worked super fine... though it's not working in my country very bad :(

Comment: Hey Dan that features are not supported in ios7 it says but i am using ios6 and still no support why?

Comment: Edited my answer. I agree, it is very bad indeed!